# Antlr4 grammar wouldn't parse multiline input

Tags: antlr4

I want to write a grammar using Antlr4 that will parse a some definition but I've been struggling to get Antlr to co-operate.

The definition has two kinds of lines, a type and a property. I can get my grammar to parse the type line correctly but it either ignores the property lines or fails to identify PROPERTY_TYPE depending on how I tweak my grammar.

Here is my grammar (attempt # 583):

```
    grammar TypeDefGrammar;

    start
        :   statement+ ;

    statement
        :   type NEWLINE
        |   property NEWLINE
        |   NEWLINE ;

    type
        :   TYPE_KEYWORD TYPE_NAME;             // e.g. 'type MyType1'

    property
        :   PROPERTY_NAME ':' PROPERTY_TYPE ;   // e.g. 'someProperty1: int'

    TYPE_KEYWORD
        :   'type' ;

    TYPE_NAME
        :   IDENTIFIER ;

    PROPERTY_NAME
        :   IDENTIFIER ;

    PROPERTY_TYPE
        :   IDENTIFIER ;

    fragment IDENTIFIER
        :   (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | DIGIT | '_' )* ;
    fragment LETTER
        :   [a-zA-Z] ;
    fragment DIGIT
        :   [0-9] ;

    NEWLINE
        :   '\r'? '\n' ;
    WS
        :   [ \t] -> skip ;
```

Here is a sample input:

```
    type SimpleType

    intProp1: int
    stringProp2 : String
```

(returns the type but ignores intProp1, stringProp2.)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Usually when a rule does not match the whole input, but does match a prefix of it, it will simply match that prefix and leave the rest of the input in the stream without producing an error. If you want your rule to always match the whole input, you can add `EOF` to the end of the rule. That way you'll get proper error messages when it can't match the entire input.

So let's change your `start` rule to `start : statement+ EOF;`. Now applying `start` to your input will lead to the following error messages:

> line 3:0 extraneous input 'intProp1' expecting {, 'type', PROPERTY_NAME, NEWLINE}
>   line 4:0 extraneous input 'stringProp2' expecting {, 'type', PROPERTY_NAME, NEWLINE}

So apparently `intProp1` and `stringProp2` aren't recognized as `PROPERTY_NAME`s. So let's look at which tokens are generated (you can do that using the `-tokens` option to `grun` or by just iterating over the token stream in your code):

```
[@0,0:3='type',<'type'>,1:0]
[@1,5:14='SimpleType',<TYPE_NAME>,1:5]
[@2,15:15='\n',<NEWLINE>,1:15]
[@3,16:16='\n',<NEWLINE>,2:0]
[@4,17:24='intProp1',<TYPE_NAME>,3:0]
[@5,25:25=':',<':'>,3:8]
[@6,27:29='int',<TYPE_NAME>,3:10]
[@7,30:30='\n',<NEWLINE>,3:13]
[@8,31:41='stringProp2',<TYPE_NAME>,4:0]
[@9,43:43=':',<':'>,4:12]
[@10,45:50='String',<TYPE_NAME>,4:14]
[@11,51:51='\n',<NEWLINE>,4:20]
[@12,52:51='<EOF>',<EOF>,5:0]
```

So all of the identifiers in the code are recognized as `TYPE_NAME`s, not `PROPERTY_NAME`s. In fact, it is not clear what should distinguish a `TYPE_NAME` from a `PROPERTY_NAME`, so now let's actually look at your grammar:

```
TYPE_NAME
    :   IDENTIFIER ;

PROPERTY_NAME
    :   IDENTIFIER ;

PROPERTY_TYPE
    :   IDENTIFIER ;

fragment IDENTIFIER
    :   (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | DIGIT | '_' )* ;
```

Here you have three lexer rules with exactly the same definition. That's a bad sign.

Whenever multiple lexer rules can match on the current input, ANTLR chooses the one that would produce the longest match, picking the one that comes first in the grammar in case of ties. This is known as the maximum munch rule.

If you have multiple rules with the same definition, that means those rules will always match on the same input and they will always produce matches of the same length. So by the maximum much rule, the first definition (`TYPE_NAME`) will always be used and the other ones might as well not exist.

The problem basically boils down to the fact that there's nothing that lexically distinguishes the different types of names, so there's no basis on which the lexer could decide which type of name a given identifier represents. That tells us that the names should not be lexer rules. Instead `IDENTIFIER` should be a lexer rule and the `FOO_NAME`s should either be (somewhat unnecessary) parser rules or removed altogether (you can just use `IDENTIFIER` wherever you're currently using `FOO_NAME`).

Comment: That was just the insight I needed. I'd separated the names because they wouldn't be just IDENTIFIER down the line. But I reworked the code to remove the matching rules and now it works. Thanks!